# zsh: command not found: on Mac os catalina in a globally installed package

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I'm not really familiar with the new z shell and not really a terminal power user, however, I'm familiar with package managers and as I was trying to install a package globally using npm install x -g, it installs successfully but I can't use the command and I get the following error

```
zsh: command not found: x
```

Echoing $PATH shows the following value

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Users/(user)/.npm-global/bin
```

I don't have a .zshrc file to edit, I'm not sure that's the default thing or not but this is a fresh installation of mac os

Comment: `.zshrc` is only sourced if it exists; you can create it if it does not. That said, `.zprofile` is the preferred place to make changes to environment variables, since a new non-login interactive shell will inherit the value of `PATH` without having to modifying it *again*.

Comment: There are a few other places `PATH` could have been edited to add your `.npm-global/bin`, though the fact that it is on your `PATH` means it's not terribly important to track down which file did it.

Comment: (I'm assuming that `(user)` is your real user ID redacted, not a literal value. If it is literal, that's the problem.)

Comment: @chepner your assumption is correct, I've replaced it, however, I'm not really sure I get the solution you're suggesting

Comment: I have no solution, because it's not clear what the problem is. If `/Users/(user)/.npm-global/bin/x` exists (and has execution permissions), you shouldn't be getting the error. So I guess make sure that `x` is actually installed where it should be (or find where it *is* installed), and make sure its permissions are something like `rwxr-xr-x`.

Comment: so I tried npm get prefix and I got this /Users/(user)/~./npm-global, would the ~. make a difference, if yes, can you help me fix it ?

Comment: I don't really know `npm`, but that looks like a problem. I would expect the prefix to be *either* `/Users/(user)/.npm-global` or `~/.npm-global`, not some sort of combination of the two. `~` isn't a real directory name; it's a shell-specific shortcut for your home directory (`/Users/(user)`), and as such should never appear the middle of *any* path, nor in a path generated by something other than the shell.

Comment: Or more to the point: `npm` itself seems to be misconfigured.

Comment: @chepner yup, that was it, the .npmrc file had prefix = .~/.npm-global, I'm not sure what caused this, but after fixing that the correct desired directory, it worked perfectly, thanks mate :)